# How to change working directory in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, working-directory

I am running SWI-Prolog (AMD64, Multi-threaded, version 7.6.4) on Windows 7.

I checked current working directory:

```
working_directory(CWD, CWD).
```

It returned:

```
CWD = 'c:/users/some.user/documents/prolog/'.
```

Now when I try to change it to:

```
 working_directory('c:/users', NewCWD).
```

it returns:

```
false
```

I also tried with the same result

```
 working_directory('c:/users/', NewCWD).
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You got the arguments backwards: `working_directory(OldCwd, 'c:/users/').`